# Don't know Server Name

Tags: sql-server, sql

I just installed SQL management studio to my computer. It opened up with window Connect to Server. What I shall write in Server Name part?

I have just started to study SQL. Where i can find Server Name?

Answer (score 2):

If you only installed Management Studio then there is no server to connect to.  You need to install the server part also.  After doing that, the server name would be the same as the computer name (assuming you chose the default options).

Here's a longer explanation:  The server part and the client part are two separate pieces.  Management Studio is the client part.  It connects to the server part, which can be on the same computer, or a different computer.  Microsoft offers the Management Studio as a separate download, and it sounds like that is what you installed.  You can also download a package that has both the server and the Management Studio in one installation package.  You should download and install that one if you want to install both the server and the client on your computer.

Answer (score -4):

Open Windows Command Processor and type hostname you will come across Server Name.  Server Name means name of your computer.

Comment: No, server name is the host name of the server hosting the SQL database.  It's only the same as hostname of the machine you're on if you're logged onto the server itself.  Generally, especially in enterprise situations, the server is in a rack in a datacenter and the administrator is in a cube in a different building/city/country/continent logging into a workstation and connecting to the database over the network.  You don't REALLY want an admin surfing the internet on the same machine that runs the database that is usually the core of a business app, do you?